# ant delete task to duplicate "rm -rf <dir>" where target may or may not be a symlink

Tags: ant

I want an Ant task to delete a directory, and replace it with a symbolic link. The task should, of course, be idempotent. This is trivial with two shell commands:

```
rm -rf <directory>
ln -s <other-directory> <directory>
```

The second step can be done with the *symlink* task. Can the first step be done with the *delete* task? I have tried

```
<delete removeNotFollowedSymlinks="true">
    <fileset dir="${some.directory}" followsymlinks="false">
</delete>
```

This deletes a physical directory but does not delete a symlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the quirky way Ant's `delete` task works, and the fact that in your case you're not sure whether the file will be a directory or a symlink, you'll have to first use the `symlink` task with the `delete` action, then the `delete` task. If you don't first try to remove the symlink, the `delete` task will delete the symlink along with the contents of the source it was pointing to.

```
<property name="dir" value="/path/to/dir" />

<!-- Set a property for consistency -->

<symlink action="delete" link="${dir}" />

<!-- If the file was a symlink, at this point it will be deleted. If it's a directory, nothing will have happened. -->

<delete dir="${dir.name}" />

<!-- If the file was a directory, it will now be deleted recursively. -->

<symlink resource="/path/to/some/other/dir" link="${dir}" />

<!-- Now the new symlink is created. -->
```

Comment: Oh! The humanity! That works, but I'm just going to use exec to run "rm -rf". Everyone knows what that does, and systems without "rm" aren't interesting.